# Automate right click save as in IE, Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: browser, selenium, automation, autoit

Does anybody know a way I can automate the right click and save as actions for IE, Chrome and Firefox?

I am doing some selenium work using Maven and need to be able to download some files but I am unable to do this as the save as windows cannot (to my knowledge) be automated by Selenium as they are OS dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Bob, Bill and the author of the article that is linked to in the other answer.

Downloads **can** be automated. The downloaded file **can** be meaningfully verified. In simplest case you can compare the contents of downloaded file with an existing exemplary file.

*(Disclaimer: the next paragraph is about a tool which I am affiliated with).*

For example if you use [RIATest](http://www.cogitek.com/riatest.html) for automation you can automate the right click, then automate the OS dialog, then wait until the download is finished and verify the content of the downloaded file.